# In PHP would this be deemed correct?

Tags: php, string, substr

I already wrote a post about an issue I had before about this but I had that issue taken care of. Like my last post I have a form, text-box and a button. I have everything done with this including Printing the original word, Printing the number of characters in the word, Printing the word in all caps and Printing the word in reverse order. My only issue I'm having is trying to get whatever text I enter and then click the button to output to Print the first letter of the word and Print the last letter of the word. I've been doing a lot of looking around of PHP.net and I found that substr is used to return a part of a string that I could use. The only issue is when I write the code for it and try to execute my program it errors out on that specific line. I'm not looking for the answer but could someone just take a look and see what I'm doing wrong because I understand everything completely but this is the only thing I'm hung up on.

```
$first = substr($_POST['entertext']);
echo "The first letter of the word is " . $first. "<br />\n"; 

$last = substr($_POST['entertext']);
echo "The first letter of the word is " . $last. "<br />\n";
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php - `$rest = substr("abcdef", -1);    // returns "f"`

Comment: You should also use the htmlspecialchars() function to make the input safe to display. E.g $first = htmlspecialchars(substr($_POST['entertext'], 0, 1));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$first = substr($_POST['entertext'], 0, 1);
echo "The first letter of the word is " . $first. "<br />\n"; 

$last = substr($_POST['entertext'], sizeof($_POST['entertext'])-2, 1);
echo "The first letter of the word is " . $last. "<br />\n";
```

Comment: Wow that works great. Just a quick question at the end past entertext what does the 0, 1 and -2, 1 do?

Comment: substr has 3 params. First: string, second: the position to start, third: length. sizeof returns the numer of letters, so for example the word "hello" will return 4. But the position of the last letter is 3 because the first is 0. You want to get the LAST letter so you have to start 1 step backwards from the last letter, so in "hello" you have to start from the last "l" position, so is sizeof($str)-2. If the answer helped you, mark it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help you seriously have helped me so much :)

Answer (score 2):

The error you're most likely seeing, if the code you've shared in your question is the code you're testing, states that [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) expects two arguments: an input string and the starting position.

For instance, your "first" character would be:

```
$first = substr($_POST['entertext'], 0, 1);
```

In this sample, there are three arguments; the first is the string you're getting the substring of. The second argument is the index of the character to start at; the optional third parameter is "how many characters to return". In this case, we're just interested in a single character at index 0.

To get the last character:

```
$last = substr($_POST['entertext'], strlen($_POST['entertext']) - 1, 1);
```

You can also take a shortcut to grab the last character and pass the "starting index" as `-1`:

```
$last = substr($_POST['entertext'], -1);
```

Comment: This works great too but just curious strlen does work in my code. When I execute it for some reason it returns the third letter of the word I put in the text-box. For example the word Donny put in the text box and run gives me the last letter to be n instead of y.

Comment: @Bill Just curious, but are you using multi-byte characters? If you're using regular ascii characters, [`strlen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) should work perfectly.